# How to override a property in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have this Class and a subclass, from the Swift tutorial. Sadly the tutorial doesn't mention how to override a property. My first test failed miserably:

```
// generic shape
class Shape {
    var numberOfSides = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return self.name + " with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}

// creating a subclass and reset the property
class Triangle: Shape {
    // this doesnt work
    override var numberOfSides = 3

    // this also doesnt work
    var numberOfSides = 3

    // and this doesnt work either
    numberOfSides = 3

    // this works
    override func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "Triangle name: " + self.name + " number of sides: \(numberOfSides)"
    }
}

var blurgh = Triangle(name: "supertriangle")
println(blurgh.simpleDescription())
```

So what is the correct way to set a property on a subclass?

Comment: I expect you want this to be a class (not instance) property -- but I think that they are not yet supported as of Xcode 6 beta 4....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you don't want to override the property you just want to change it value. 
The best way to do that is init method:

```
init(name: String) {
    super.init(name: name)
    numberOfSides = 3
}
```

To override property you should make some change to it getter or setter method, for example:

```
override var numberOfSides  {
    get {
        return super.numberOfSides
    }
    set {
        super.numberOfSides = newValue + 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the init method?

```
...

func init() {
    super.init()

    self.numberOfSides = 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to extend **Greg**'s answer. Along with `get` and `set` there are `willSet` and `didSet` options. Copy next code to playground and play with it to see how you can use it

```
import UIKit

class TestClass {
    var testValue: String = ""
    var anotherProperty: String = ""
}

class AnotherTestClass: TestClass {
    override var testValue: String {
        didSet {
            if countElements(super.testValue) > 2 {
                super.testValue = "222"
            }
        }
        willSet {
            if countElements(newValue) > 2 {
                super.anotherProperty = "33"
            }
        }
    }
}

var c: AnotherTestClass = AnotherTestClass()
c.testValue = "123"
```